# Stirling Numbers Exponential Generating Function Induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, generating-functions, stirling-numbers, bell-numbers

I was reading the solution to a question written [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522186/exponential-generating-function-stirling-numbers), and it uses a fact which can be proved by induction.

The question is to show that an EGF for Stirling Numbers of the second kind with fixed $k$,  \begin{eqnarray*}
S_k(x)=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} S_{n,k} \frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{eqnarray*} has a closed form: \begin{eqnarray*}
  S_k(x)=\frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!}
\end{eqnarray*}
However, I have been trying for a while and I have been unable to figure out the inductive step, especially when it comes to using the given fact $\frac{d}{dx}  S_k(x)=kS_k(x)+S_{k-1}(x)$. Any help to proceed with the inductive step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to solve the ODE
$$
\frac{d}{dx}S_{k+1}(x)-(k+1)S_{k+1}(x)=S_k(x). \tag{1}
$$
Multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by the integrating factor $e^{-(k+1)x}$, and using the induction hypothesis $S_k(x)=\frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!}$, we obtain
\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{-(k+1)x}S_{k+1}(x)\right]=e^{-(k+1)x}\frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!}
=\frac{e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})^k}{k!} \\
&\quad\implies S_{k+1}(x)=e^{(k+1)x}\left(C+\int\frac{e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})^k}{k!} \,dx\right).
\tag{2}
\end{align}
To compute the integral, we make the substitution $u=-e^{-x}, u=e^{-x}dx$:
\begin{align}
S_{k+1}(x)&=e^{(k+1)x}\left(C+\int\frac{(1+u)^k}{k!}\,du\right) \\
&=e^{(k+1)x}\left(C+\frac{(1+u)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\right) \\
&=e^{(k+1)x}\left(C+\frac{(1-e^{-x})^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\right) \\
&=Ce^{(k+1)x}+\frac{(e^x-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
To determine the constant $C$, we notice that $S_{k+1}(x)=\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} S_{n,k+1} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ implies $S_{k+1}(0)=0$, hence $C=0$. Therefore,
$$
S_{k+1}(x)=\frac{(e^x-1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}.\quad{\square} \tag{4}
$$